# PostgreSQL Select Columns Then Add Random Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

SOLVED! Thanks Gordon Linoff!

Is it possible to get query result like this in PostgreSQL?

```
UserName | Count |
Sukri    |   1   |
Azis     |   2   |
Adit     |   1   |
Total    |   4   |
```

The row "Total" value is the sum of 3 columns.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN (res."UserName"IS NULL OR res."UserName" = '') THEN 'TOTAL' 
    ELSE res."UserName"
END AS "UserName",
res."Count"
FROM
(
    SELECT "UserName", count("UserName") AS "Count"
    FROM "Ticket"
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( ("UserName"), () ) ORDER BY "UserName"
) AS res
```

Comment: There is no chance to answer this when we don't know the tables you are selecting from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess this is an aggregation query.  If so, use `grouping sets` (or `rollup`):

```
select coalesce(username, 'Total') as userid, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by grouping sets ( (username), () );
```

Comment: That works! It returns the sum of count column, but the username column returns null...

Comment: The result is like this:

UserName | Count |
Sukri    |   1   |
Azis     |   2   |
Adit     |   1   |
[null]    |   4   |